# Controlling what text SQL Server's Full-text Engine indexes in a nvarchar column

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

We have a nvarchar(max) column which is full-text indexed. In the text stored in this column there are whole phrases/sentences/paragraphs which should be ignored when carrying out full-text searches. For example, let's there are rows which contain "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" and you don't want that phrase indexed because "fox" in that context should be ignored but if "fox" occurs in other parts of the text it is relevant and should not be ignored.

Is there any way to filter the text the full-text indexing engine reads from the column so that it does not index these phrases?

A more concrete example: The body of emails is stored in the database. Is there a way to leave all the signatures/virus checker info within the text of the email, but completely ignore it when doing full-text searches?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports [Stopwords and Stoplists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx), check them out. But those are related to individual words. Not sure you will be able to filter whole phrases with stopwords/stoplists.

I think the only option you have is to prepare/cleanse your data. For this, remove your original `nvarchar(max)` column from the full-text index and instead add a new column (say `fts_col2`) to your table which would hold prepared/filtered data for the full text search. Then add this new column to the full-text index.

When your original column gets inserted or updated you should insert/update data in the `fts_col2` using insert/update triggers. Inside these triggers run all your custom filtering against the value of the original `nvarchar(max)` column being inserted/updated.

Or alternatively, during insert/update you would copy original column data into `fts2_col` as is but also set up a nightly or hourly process/job to periodically check all new/updated records in your FTS-indexed table and extract all *noise* words/phrases from the `fts_col2`. SQL Server will automatically rebuild Full-Text index when it detects `fts_col2` values have changed.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, we had considered stopwords and a 2nd column. I also assume that stopwords can only be single words, though I haven't tested this assumption. The problem with the 2nd column is the duplication of data. I will add an answer which outlines what we are considering doing instead

Comment: @PhilHaselden yes, second FTS index-ed column means data duplication, but it also provides the ease of use because you will be getting the right record from FTS search instantly, no need for extra JOINs. Your Noisephrases approach may also work but if your original table contains say 1 million of records even with as little as 2 noise phrases per email you will 2 millions records in the DocumentNoisephrase table which must be searched and JOIN-ed upon every view request. You will also have to properly handle inserts/updates/deletions into main table and update the noise tables too.

Comment: @PhilHaselden to continue previous comment...so from my SQL Server FTS experience the best approach in terms of performance would be to feed FTS engine with the final version of data even if it comes with data duplication cost. Moreover, external search engines like lucene/solr and elasticsearch do exactly the same: they take your data from multiple joined tables, construct 1 big flat 'table/view' which they FTS-index then. This way they are able to provide search results with various aggregation sum()/count() counts instantly.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to extract the noise-phrases into a separate table, along with information about the original character position of the extracted phrase. When it is time to display the whole text, we would reconstruct the document by inserting the extracted noise-phrase(s) back into the original location(s).

Since the noise-phrases are common, the end solution would probably include 2 extra tables. The Noisephrase table containing an ID and the phrase, and a DocumentNoisephrase table with columns: DocumentID, NoisephraseID, CharPosition, and ExtractionOrder.